# MySQL Getting last record for each conditions

Tags: mysql

I need some help for a query.

Basic table structure :

```
user_id     user_status
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           2
5           2
```

I want to get last user_id 's for each user_status. Just like this result :

```
user_id     user_status
3           1
5           2
```

Thanks for your helps in advance.

Comment: perhaps `select max(user_id) as user_id,user_status from table group by user_status` would be the simplest one.

Comment: Thank you @AbhikChakraborty, sometimes brain stops working :) Could you please add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sql is useful to you. please execute and see.

```
 SELECT MAX(user_id),user_status FROM table_name 
  WHERE user_status IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_status FROM table_name)
  GROUP BY user_status
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `max` and `group by`

```
select max(user_id) as user_id,user_status from table group by user_status
```